# Probability of getting two red balls is 1/2. How small can the number of balls in the box be?

Tags: probability

The question is this:

> In a box, there are red balls and blue balls. If you take two balls at random, the probability of getting two red balls is $\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> 1.How small can the number of balls in the box be?
>
> 2. If the number of blue balls in the box is even, then, how small can the number of balls in the box be?

So far, I've figured out that $\frac{R}{R+B}\times\frac{R-1}{R+B-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and got nothing else.

(R=number of red balls in the box, B=# of blue balls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{R}{R+B}\times\dfrac{R-1}{R+B-1} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Simplifying and rearranging,

$R =  0.5(\sqrt{8B^2+1}+2 B+1)$

Since the **minimum** number of balls is needed to make the equation true, we start with $B=1$, and hit the nail on the head  right away for part $1: B = 1, R = 3$

For part $2$, going back to our original formulation, $R$ can be either odd or even.

- If it is odd, we get ${\text{odd}\over \text{odd}}\times{\text{even}\over \text{even}}= \frac12 $
- If it is even, we get ${\text{even}\over \text{even}}\times{\text{odd}\over \text{odd}} = \frac12 $

Neither is possible.

Answer (score 2):

We start from $\frac{R}{N}\frac{R-1}{N-1}=\frac{1}{2}$, where $R$ = Number of red balls, $N$ = Total number of balls ($B$ = Number of blue balls).

If the two previous fractions are already expressed with coprime factors, and given the fact that neither $R$ or $R-1$, and neither $N$ or $N-1$ are even, two of the four factors must cancel to hold the equation. This leads to $R=N-1$ (the other three possibilities make no sense) and this new equation:

$$\frac{a}{a+1}\frac{a-1}{a}=\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow \frac{a-1}{a+1}=\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow a =3$$

Then we have $R=3$, $B=1$, $N=4$.

If the fractions $\frac{R}{N}$ and $\frac{R-1}{N-1}$ are not expressed with coprime factors, we could always simplify to arrive to that situation, with the only possible solution for our equation being $\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{3}$. This product could represent the probability of extracting two red balls from a box of 40 balls (30 R, 10 B), if we take out 10 red ones for the second extraction, for example. But for the problem we have, **the only possibility that respects the conditions** is the previously found $R=3$, $B=1$, $N=4$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to get a rigorous proof, but a straightforward way would be to try different values of $B (0, 1, 2, ...)$ and solve for $R$.

1. $B = 0$ is impossible as all balls are red, so $B$ is at least 1;
2. $B = 1$, the equation gives $R = 3$

I believe the answer to the first question is four: three red balls and one blue ball.

For the second question it is better to write $R$ as $2x$ and derive an analytical expression of $x$ in $B$, and enumerate $B$ until $x$ becomes integer. The expression is

$$x =\frac{1 + 2B + \sqrt{1+8B^2}}{4}$$

So the task is to get integer $x$ with integer $B$, I did a quick attempt with Mathematica, but for the first 100,000 integers $x$ was still non-integer. I wish some one can shed more light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your equation to get a quadratic, solve for $R$ in terms of $B$.  Plot and make observations.

$2R(R-1) = (R+B)~((R-1)+B) \\ 2R(R-1) = R(R-1) + (2R-1)B+B^2 \\ R(R-1) = (2R-1)B+B^2 \\ R^2-(1+2B)R  +(B-B^2) = 0 \\ R = \tfrac 1 2 (\sqrt{~8 B^2+1~}+2 B+1)$

(Note: the other quadratic root leads to non-positive $R$ for $B>1$ so can be ignored.)

What is the minimum positive integer $R$ when $R\geq 2$ and $B\geq 1$?

What is the minimum $B+R$ when $B+R$ is even (and $B\geq 1$ and $R\geq 2$)?